# How to SQL Query Last Day of the Month that has transaction?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

My set of data are as follows:

```
+------+-------+-----+--------+
| Year | Month | Day | Amount |
+------+-------+-----+--------+
| 2019 |    01 |  01 |     10 |
| 2019 |    01 |  15 |     30 |
| 2019 |    01 |  29 |     40 |
| 2019 |    02 |  02 |     50 |
| 2019 |    02 |  22 |     60 |
| 2019 |    03 |  11 |     70 |
| 2019 |    03 |  31 |     80 |
+------+-------+-----+--------+
```

I just want to see the last record day of each month that has transaction.

My preferred result shown should look like this:

```
+------+-------+--------+
| Year | Month | Amount |
+------+-------+--------+
| 2019 |    01 |     40 |
| 2019 |    02 |     60 |
| 2019 |    03 |     80 |
+------+-------+--------+
```

Comment: try something like `select * from tablename where 1 like 1 groupby Month orderby Day.`

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each combination of `Year` and `Month`, you want to get the maximum `Day` and `Amount` values:

```
SELECT Year, Month, max(Day) as Day, max(Amount) as Amount
FROM t
GROUP BY Year, Month;
```

Note that every column appearing in the `SELECT` clause but not in the `GROUP BY` clause must be aggregated (with `max` here).

That is, assuming `Amount` corresponds to the total per day, which is what your example suggests.

If your table contains more than one `Amount` per day, then you also need to sum up the amounts per day. I'd use something like:

```
SELECT Year, Month, max(Day) as Day, max(Amount) as Amount
FROM (
  SELECT Year, Month, Day, sum(Amount) as Amount 
  FROM t
  GROUP BY Year, Month, Day
) as tmp
GROUP BY Year, Month;
```

[test me](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/b3666/4)  (with one more amount added to your example)

Or:

```
SELECT Year, Month, Day, sum(Amount) as Amount
FROM (
  SELECT *, rank() over(partition by Year, Month order by Day desc) as r
  FROM t
) as tmp
WHERE r = 1
GROUP BY Year, Month, Day;
```

Mind that you want to use `rank()` and not `row_number()` in here, as you need to give the same rank identifier to ties (same day).

Of course if you want you can wrap any of the queries above with:

```
SELECT Year, Month, Amount
FROM (<query>) as q;
```

to get rid of the day column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use row number to achieve this:

```sql
SELECT [Year], [Month], [Amount]
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CONCAT(YEAR,MONTH) ORDER BY DAY DESC) rn, *
    FROM table) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.day = (select max(t2.day)
               from t t2
               where t2.year = t.year and t2.month = t.month
              );
```

Another common approach uses `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by year, month order by day desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can QUALIFY use below:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY YEAR, MONTH ORDER BY DAY DESC) as rn, *
    FROM yourtable
    QUALIFY rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ROW_NUMBER() function:

```
with cte_order as (select year, month, amount,row_number() over(partition by month order by day desc) as identity_row from test1)
```

select year, month, amount from cte_order where identity_row = 1;

Using QUALIFY() function:

```
select year, month, amount, day, row_number() over(partition by month order by day desc) as identity_row from test1 qualify identity_row = 1;
```

Answer (score -3):

`select  year,month,amount  from(SELECT  year,month,max(day),amount FROM  t   GROUP BY year,month);`

Comment: have you tried your SELECT !!! I'm sure that it was rejected because any aggregation function was applied to AMOUNT column !

Comment: Unfortunately this is what sloppy MySQL teaches. It allows to leave it non-aggregated. Any sane RDBMS would reject it. But this query isn't valid SQL also for another reason - even on MySQL. Sub-queries are required to be aliased.